# MVC Pass the view model into embedded javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a strongly typed IEnumerable as the Model for one of my views.
I'm iterating over that model in the view to display the content of each model in a HTML table where each row represents a model.
When the user clicks on one of the rows, I'd like the model of that row to render in a jquery dialog where it displays the model content in a pop up.
Can someone explain how to pass these C# objects to the jQuery dialog function, or any other alternative method to achieve this would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
View Model
public class DTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"\d+(\.\d{0})?")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}


View
@model IEnumerable<DTO>

<div id="expenses-list"">
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <table class="table borderless">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="input-group-horiz">Expense</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                @Html.Partial("Item", item);
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    }
</div>



Partial View
@model DTO

<div id="@Model.Id">
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Type</td>
    <td>@Model.Amount</td>

    <td><a onclick="DisplayDialog(@Model)"><img src="~/content/images/153-check.png" /></a></td>
    <td><img src="~/Content/Images/17-bin.png"></td>
</tr>
</div>


JQuery Dialog
<script>

function DisplayDialog(model) {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Add Expense',
        width: 800,
        open: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have an action method which takes an `Id` and return the partial view result and use that as the model popup content. You are action method can use the `Id` to get the data needed in the model content

Comment: Post your code, it will help us to help you.

Comment: thanks Shyju. I thought about that approach but I don't see the point in passing the action method the model id to get the model content when I already have all the model content I need in the parent view. Is it possible to just pass the entire model to the action method rather than its Id?

Comment: Broad answer : "Yes". If you want more specific answer, share the relevant code and your expected results.

Comment: Rather than calling an action method with an Id, should I just directly call the Partial View and pass in my model object?

Comment: If all the fields are available in your page view model, store the page view model to a js array and when the model needs to be populated, get the item from this array and use it.